# Hibernate.initialize method. How to guarantee?

Tags: java, hibernate

From hibernate JavaDoc:

> **public static void initialize(Object proxy)
>                          throws HibernateException**
>
> Force initialization of a proxy or persistent collection.
>
> Note: This only ensures intialization of a proxy object or collection;
>   it is **not guaranteed** that the elements INSIDE the collection will
>   be initialized/materialized.

**But how to make this guaranteed?**

I have a collection, and it is lazy loaded (default for @OneToMany). Consider one of the collections entry property is @Lob, or contain some other lazy initiated object (lazy is default for @Lob, or marked lazy explicitly). How to make the collection initialization in manner **to be sure** that inner property of collection entry is initialized eager or lazy?

Is it possible at all with Hibernate.initialize method? Should I use something different instead?

Comment: If possible, i would not use the initialize method at all. Use the proper annotations(`FetchType.EAGER`), fetch profiles(Criterias) or fetch joins(HQL). It all depends on the way you query your objects.

Comment: It looks like you misunderstand the question. I can query objects or get reference to just newly saved, any way I have a Hibernate Entity object with lazy initiated collection. The session is still open. Now the collections entries have lazy annotated properties, but they are not guaranteed to be initiated. I am looking for solution to make their initiation (or not initiation) guaranteed at runtime. Of cause I not want to have @Lob annotated with FetchType.EAGER as you propose! They should be lazy as default, but initialize method can load them or not and this behavior not guaranteed.